# How to stylize parent CSS class which has a specific child

Tags: jquery, html, css, background

I'm trying to figure out how to effect a parent class that has a particular child. As far as I can tell this is not possible with CSS3, but it might be possible with jQuery.

Here is the parent class `.home .x-navbar`

Here is the child class`.x-btn-navbar`

CSS I want to add to the parent class:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%) !important;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) !important;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%) !important;
```

What jQuery code would I need to achieve effecting a parent classes css when it has a specific child?

Answer (score 0):

```
var defaultCssRule = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%) !important";
var myWebkitRule = "-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) !important";
$(".home .x-navbar .x-btn-navbar").parents(".x-navbar").css({
    "background": myCssRule,
    "background": myWebkitRule
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. I think this is the Jquery code you would need:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $(".x-btn-navbar").parent();
  element.css({"background": "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%) !important",
 "background":" -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37) 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%) !important"});
 });
```